# What kind of pump do I need for this valve?

Tags: pump, valves

[image: Valve]

This is the valve I have on my bike, but my current pump does not work with it. What kind of pump do I need to buy that will work with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a Presta Valve. Your pump, I am going to guess, is a Schrader Valve. You can buy a Presta pump from a shop or buy a $2 adapter.

[image: a $2 adapter]

Answer (score 4):

It may be that your current pump actually supports this valve, but the application may not be obvious. You may need, for example, to push the valve deeper into the pump than may appear possible at first; only then the corresponding valve or rubber o-ring in the pump will yield.

If this is the first time you see this valve then maybe you just don't know that you need to open the valve by turning it counterclockwise (when it's pointing up).

Comment: On some pumps you unscrew the ring on the chuck, reverse the "innards", and re-install the ring.

Comment: And, yes, to prepare the valve for filling you need to unscrew the knurled piece all the way until it stops (don't force) and then give the tip of the valve a little press to free the rubber gasket.  When done, retighten the knurled piece, but only just finger tight -- over-tightening will just cause the rubber gasket inside to fail sooner.

Comment: In this case, I'd definitely need an adapter. I opened the valve, tried pushing it in again and ended up deflating the tire entirely.

Comment: Just in case, you might want to consider posting the picture of your pump end, as well. There might be a way.